# Changing html value of clicked element among other elements with same class after AJAX response received

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am pretty much new to JQuery. I can't seem to work around a function where html of an element needs to be changed once Ajax response has been received. This element shares same class with other elements too.

HTML:

```
<div id="custManage">
    <span class="blockUnblock">Block</span>
    <span class="blockUnblock">Unblock</span>
    <span class="blockUnblock">Block</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#custManage .blockUnblock').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some Code
    $.ajax({
            // Some Code
            success: function (response){
                // I am able to receive AJAX response here
                $(this).text('Changed'); // Clicked span
                $(this).html('Changed'); // This also doesn't work
            }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$(this)` changes once you enter the success function.

Try doing this:

```
$('#custManage .blockUnblock').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    // Some Code
    $.ajax({
            // Some Code
            success: function (response){
                // I am able to receive AJAX response here
                $this.text('Changed');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes that indeed work. Accepting answer in 7 minutes.